# Stop on each element after a scroll in ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I am using ScrollView in my react native app.
Currently, it's rendering well.

But what I want is - *When I scroll, it should focus/stop at the next element.*

Is there any method of ScrollView to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you implement pagination in `scrollView` you can achieve this.

add this prop to `scrollView`

```
<ScrollView
...
pagingEnabled={true}
...
>
...
</ScrollView>
```

This can be used for horizontal pagination(Both iOS and Android). Vertical pagination is not supported on Android.